# Stripping a specific part of variable in SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a variable where i dynamically store the URL

For Eg. a="https://myaccessdev.searshc.com/aveksa/main?Oid=1&ReqType=GetPage&ObjectClass=com.aveksa.gui.objects.workflow.GuiWorkflowJob&WFObjectID=3478:WPDS"

I want to strip the number in the last before ":WDPS" from this whole string.

Is there any way of doing it in SQL

Comment: Yes there are ways to do this. I'm I correct in thinking you want the number between `WFObjectID=`and`:WPDS` (that is 3478 but could be of any length)?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to strip the number [...] before ":WDPS" from this whole string.

This is a perfect match for [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
with test_data as
 (select 'https://myaccessdev.searshc.com/aveksa/main?Oid=1&ReqType=GetPage&ObjectClass=com.aveksa.gui.objects.workflow.GuiWorkflowJob&WFObjectID=3478:WPDS' str
  from dual)

select REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '.*=([0-9]*):WPDS.*', '\1') from test_data
--                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^
--       replace everything before and after       by the first capturing
--                         the target string       group (i.e.: the sequence between
--                                                 parenthesis in the regular expression)
```

Producing:

```
3478
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/37095 for a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @string varchar(255) = 'https://myaccessdev.searshc.com/aveksa/main?Oid=1&ReqType=GetPage&ObjectClass=com.aveksa.gui.objects.workflow.GuiWorkflowJob&WFObjectID=3478:WPDS'

DECLARE @end varchar(10) = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string),0,CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE(@string))))

SELECT SUBSTRING(@end,0,CHARINDEX(':', @end))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number, you can do something like this:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(s, '=[0-9]*:WPDS', 1, 1), '[0-9]*', 1, 1)
```

You can do this with `regexp_substr()`.  I'm having trouble testing it right now.  The following comes quite close:

```
select regexp_substr(s, '=[0-9]*:WPDS', 1, 1)
```